# Модели джанго(дерего каталог)

Tags: python, django

Можно ли как-нибудь реализвать, чтобы модель была сама для себя связана один ко многим, что я имеею ввиду

```
from django.db import models


class Menu(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Menu, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

В этом примере еще нету класса Menu, поэтому он ругается!
Для чего мне это? Я хочу сделать меню, которое будет состоять из подменю, а подменю может состоять из подподменю) и т.д, а для этого надо помнить родителя. Может советом подскажите, как такое реализовать(Идея с 2 моделями мне не оч нравится от слова совсем, т.к это только 2 уровень вложенности получается)

[image: что-то типа такого]

Comment: что такое "дерего"?

Comment: дополнил ответ про дерего

Comment: не ответ, а вопрос. но, все-таки, что такое "дерего"? так-то по вопросу вроде речь про "дерево", но мало ли...

Answer (score 3):

С помощью self:

```py
parent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='submenu')
```

Comment: Да да спасибо, я к этому тоже пришел :)